# Revert git reset HEAD to last commit changes

Tags: git, reset

By mistake i have executed below commands

```
git reset HEAD
git reset 'HEAD@{1}'
git reset ORIG_HEAD
```

Now my latest changes are not showing on remote server.

Which command need to execute i'm on dev branch

Comment: afaik, the three commands you have there should not affect the remote server

Comment: I executed on server @jbu

Comment: What do you mean by you executed these commands on the server?

Comment: I have 2 copies local & remote. So I have executed above command on server linux console

Comment: Hmmm...If your local copy is bona fide you _could_ just force push it out, e.g. `git push --force origin master`.

Comment: I'm on `dev` branch. So it should be `git push --force origin dev` ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the output of `git reflog` you should be able to figure out on which commit you want to be and switch to it with a `git reset 'HEAD@{?}'`.

Comment: `git reflog` showing details related to master branch not dev

Comment: Can you update your post with all relevent information such as what type is your server (bare or not)? where did you run these commands? Do you have non committed changes that you care about?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your `desired commit` you want to back from `git log --walk-reflogs`. Then `reset` your branch (`dev`) to the `commit-sha`.

```
$ git checkout dev
$ git log --walk-reflogs        # copy desired commit-sha

$ git reset --hard <commit-sha> # reset 'dev' branch on the commit

$ git push -f origin HEAD       # force(-f) push as history is changed
```